# Jquery count closing divs

Tags: jquery, match

How can I count the occurence of closing divs

```
$("body").html().match(/\/div/gi).length;
```

The Code above is not working as expected, although I escaped the slash.
https://jsfiddle.net/zjqtpje4/1/

Comment: Firstly, *never use Regex to parse HTML*. Secondly, the number of closing div tags will always be equal to the number of opening div tags as the browser will automatically insert any mismatching tags. Therefore you can just use `$('div').length`

Comment: That's too bad because I want to have a function to discover open-divs. The Information with the browser aside: Shouldn't the match-function not be able to count the substring "</div>" properly?

Comment: In which case you would need to find a method of parsing the string without placing it in the DOM. Personally I'm not even sure if that's possible.

Comment: You can check that easily in whatever editor you use. Just do a search for `<div` and it should return a total number of results, then search for `</div`. If the numbers match you are good to go

Comment: I want an automatism for a big website, so copy paste into editors would be too time consuming.

Comment: If the editor is of any worth it should fix mis-matching tag errors automatically. If the one you are using does not, find another one.

Comment: It's the output of a contao website where admins can insert their own html, that's why I want to check the output. Also can you edit the fiddle so it finds the ONE closing div?

Comment: I'm afraid not. As I mentioned then browser will fix the HTML, so there will always be 3 closing divs in your sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, [*never use Regex to parse HTML*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/519413).

Secondly, the number of closing div tags will always be equal to the number of opening div tags as the browser will automatically insert any mismatching tags.

You can see this behaviour in the console of the below snippet. Two closing `</div>` will be added to the code:

```js
console.log($("body").html().match(/\/div/gi).length);
console.log($('body').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
```

The only way this could work is if you can work with the HTML as a string before it is placed in the DOM. This will prevent the HTML being corrected.